# How to autodoc a custom descriptor like a property in sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a custom descriptor

```py
@runtime_checkable
class ROProperty(Protocol[T_co]):
    """Protocol for a read-only descriptor."""

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: Any = None) -> T_co | None:
        ...

class ConcreteDesc(ROProperty[T_co]):
    ...
```

I use it for a class attribute:

```py
prop = ConcreteDesc[int]()
```

I connect a function in Sphinx `conf.py`:

```py
def descriptor_annotations(app, what, name, obj, options, signature, return_annotation):
    if isinstance(obj, ROProperty) and not isinstance(obj, property):
        return ("", f"{obj.__orig_class__.__args__[0].__name__} | None")

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-process-signature", descriptor_annotations)
```

My actual goal is to get a docstring indistinguishable from a real property:

> *property* **prop** -> *type | None*

but, this gives me:

> **owner.prop -> type | None**

I tried connecting to `autodoc-before-process-signature` event as well, but then `descriptor_annotations` was called only for dunder methods, *which I think is weird*.